# Why dml error logging ignored in parallel statement

Tags: oracle, error-handling, parallel-processing

I have `insert-select` statement that I'm executing in parallel.

I'm trying to add a `dml error logging` for capture the exceptions.

But when I'm alter the session to use parallel the error logging just ignored.

```
-- This is my error table:
TRUNCATE TABLE DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV;

-- This code is finish with no error and insert rows to DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'alter session enable parallel dml';

INSERT
        /*+ monitor parallel(1) */
INTO    DWH.PURCHASE
select *
FROM    DWH.PURCHASE_C LOG ERRORS
INTO    DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV ('DWH.PURCHASE') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;

commit;
END;
```

But when I'm running this code (parallel 6) - there is an exception (ORA-12801)
and the error table doesn't has any change:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'alter session enable parallel dml';
INSERT
        /*+ monitor parallel(6) */
INTO    DWH.PURCHASE
select *
FROM    DWH.PURCHASE_C LOG ERRORS
INTO    DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV ('DWH.PURCHASE') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
commit;
END;
```

This difference also appear if I'm enabling or disabling the `alter-session`.

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Accoring to the Oracle documents, I didn't saw any restriction of using `dml error logging` with `parallel`..

Comment: `ORA-12801` is a generic error message that indicates when one of multiple threads dies.  It might help to capture the entire error stack and post it here.  There are some errors that won't cause logging, such as `ORA-00600`.

Comment: My mistake,  the specific error was of PK constraint violited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [error_logging_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423)

> Restrictions on DML Error Logging
>
> - The following conditions cause the statement to fail and roll back without invoking the error logging capability:
>
>   ...
>
>   - Any direct-path INSERT or MERGE operation that raises a unique constraint or index violation.

Parallel DML uses direct-path writes by default but you can disable direct-path with the hint `NOAPPEND`.  That will allow the statement to use parallelism but with conventional writes.  It's not as fast as parallel direct-path writes, but it's at least better than single-threaded conventional writes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I just didn't understand.  I didn't have any append hint,  the only change is with parallel...  why optimizer will choose a direct path insert when parallel is enable?

Comment: @user2671057 Direct-path writes are the default when parallel DML is used.  I made a small update to my answer.

Comment: Now it's make sense. Thank you!