# Nologging with noappend mode

Tags: oracle, performance, logging

I want to execute insert statement with `nologging`.

As I can see, the only way is to use the `APPEND` hint in the query.

The problem is that the `APPEND` hint can't work with `DML ERROR LOGGING` clause.

In my case, I must use that clause.

What is the connection between `APPEND` (that actually mean to spit all the data in the end of table and not check for blocks "holes") to the `(no)logging`? How can I apply a `nologging` with `NOAPPEND` mode?

I tried to alter-nologging the table, but the REDO is just grow when the statement is with `NOAPPEND` hint.

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`APPEND` hints and `NOLOGGING` options are just different ways to switch between direct-path writes and conventional writes.  The `APPEND` hints are used in SQL statements, and `NOLOGGING` is an option for a table or tablespace.

The problem here is that [direct-path writes do not work with DML error logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450244/409172), and as far as I know there is no direct workaround.  There is no magic combination of hints and options to make those features work together.

There are potentially other ways to improve the performance.  For example, the statement can run in parallel but with conventional writes.  Or, if you're only interested in logging the errors for a few specific constraints, you could disable those constraints, perform the change in a direct-path write, enable the constraints and record the [constraint exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11553), and then remove the rows that block the constraint.

Comment: As I see that, there are 2 different actions: one for put the data in the end of table and the second is logging in redo. I'm not sure why oracle make this dependency, that I can't apply nologging with noappend mode. I need the dml error logging because I have massive loads and can't be sure that the data is correct so the constraints need to work, and the error logging writes the problematic rows in some table. I didn't understand your constraint logging solution. what is a constraint logging and how it can help if the rows are already in the table?

Comment: @user2671057 I see what you mean about the two different actions of logging and appending; that makes sense, but Oracle doesn't allow you to have one without the other.  Sorry I used the wrong wording - it's "constraint exception", not "constraint logging".

Comment: Thank you. I think that I just can't disable the (unique) constraints because there are unique indexes... can I?

Comment: @user2671057 Yes, you can `ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE/ENABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;`.  Although dropping and re-enabling constraints will drop and recreate the index, which can generate REDO.  To avoid that redo generation, you have to manually recreate the index with a `NOLOGGING` option, and then re-enable the constraint with the `USING` clause to use the existing index.  It's a mess, but it can be done.